# Node json request badly parsed

Tags: json, node.js, curl, express, body-parser

I have the following service:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

var new_log = function(req, res){
    console.log("REQ:\n" + JSON.stringify(req.body));
    res.end();
}
```

and trying with curl:
curl.exe -X POST -d '{"holder_name":"34cbfb95"}' http://MY_SERVER:8550/api/new-log/

and the printed object in console is {"'{holder_name:34cbfb95}'":""}
Like it doesn't know its already json

If I put -H "Accept: application/json" it's the same
and if I put -H "Content-Type: application/json"
it just says unexpected token '
if I remove the single quotes from the command it says unexpected token h

Comment: Try for this curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"holder_name":"34cbfb95"}' http://MY_SERVER:8550/api/new-log/

Comment: I tried that, it's in the answer-> it says unexpected token as if it wasn't a json object

Comment: Try, -H "Content-type: application/json", `t` in `Content-type` must be in small letter